# How to import local monorepo typescript package in Angular apps?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, monorepo, pnpm

I'm trying to integrate an Angular project into a PNPM workspace monorepo that mainly contains react app. Here is the directory structure

```
|-apps
|  |-react-app
|  |  |-package.json
|  |
|  |-angular-app (new)
|    |-package.json
|
|
|-packages
|  |-shared
|     |-index.ts
|     |-package.json
|
|-package.json
|-pnpm-workspace.yaml
```

Lets say the shared package has the name `@my-app/shared` and it has `"main": "index.ts"`.

In the `react-app`, I can install this local package and directly use it in my code like the following

```
import { someValue } from '@my-app/shared';
```

With some adjustment to the webpack config, the `react-app` is able to include the shared module in the bundle correctly.

However, I couldn't figure out how to do it in an angular app. The package can install correctly and everything, but when I run the development server, seems that it doesn't include the `@my-app/shared` into the bundle

```
import { value } from '@my-app/shared';
console.log('xxx', value);
```

[image]

When I inspected the bundle, seems that the angular compiler does not bundle the module. Instead it just shows the placeholder

[image]

How do you import local package in Angular then? I believe there needs to be some config added to the `angular.json` but I couldn't find any resource. All of the sources out there points to Angular Library through `ng generate library`, which isn't what I'm looking for since `@my-app/shared` just a simple typescript utils functions.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem - any type in Angular client that's from a monorepo project comes as undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't :(

Comment: Hey, a few months later I'm also facing this issue.. were you able to solve it?

Comment: @dayujabif you can try the solution by Ryan below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, I investigated why, here's what I found ⤵️

It's basically due to typescript not emitting any ts files stored in `node_modules` (you can check it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6e4aa901f25ffa90096dc0cc1d0dd13243dec3e6/src/compiler/program.ts#L2662)).

When angular is compiling your application, it compiles files using the typescript compiler: since typescript detects the file as an external library, it is excluded, so nothing is emitted for this file.

**Why it works with your react app:**

I suppose, you had to set `allowTsInNodeModules` to `true` right? The `ts-loader` is solving this issue in the webpack plugin, but `@angular/cli` does not implement any workaround.

**Why it works with `paths`:**

When typescript analyzes the list of files to compile, it does not check by looking at a specific `node_modules` pattern in the file path:

- Instead, it maintains a `currentNodeModulesDepth` variable (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6e4aa901f25ffa90096dc0cc1d0dd13243dec3e6/src/compiler/program.ts#L3644)).
- When we use `paths`, the `currentNodeModulesDepth` is seen equal to zero, as typescript found a mapping and, so, did not start to look at `node_modules`.
- So in this case, it is correctly included in the final output.

Note that you can simplify your workaround with:

```
"paths": {
  "@my-app/*": ["../../packages/*"]
}
```

So, you don't have to list all dependencies, you can use `*` as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem.  Unfortunately, the only way I've been able to resolve it is using tsconfig paths.

Assuming the above structure:

```
|-apps
|  |-react-app
|  |  |-package.json
|  |
|  |-angular-app (new)
|    |-package.json
|    |-tsconfig.app.json
|
|
|-packages
|  |-shared
|     |-index.ts
|     |-package.json
|
|-package.json
|-pnpm-workspace.yaml
```

Note the file at `apps/angular-app/tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
       "@my-app/shared": ["../../packages/shared/index.ts"]
    },
    // ... the rest of your options
  }
}
```

This has the unfortunate downside of the angular-app having to recompile the entire `shared` package whenever there's a change.  Imo, it's better than nothing.  If there's a better way, I'd love to know!

Comment: I tried and its working, thank you so much! Although it's not ideal because we have to list out each shared dependencies individually, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Also, I think the `tsconfig.app.json` is usually inside `src` folder, so it should be `"@my-app/shared": ["../../../packages/shared/index.ts"]`